# Custom Fields: Access other data assoc. with Object other than its fields

Tags: lightning-experience, custom-field, standard-objects

I want to make a custom field for Salesforce's Contact object; I would like to access information that can be found on the Contact object page, but are NOT fields. [image]

Notice in the picture, I want to access the information highlighted. However, this information are not fields. I do not know what they are called, and I do not know how to access this information for my custom Contact field (it is supposed to count how many loans the contact is assoc. with, which is the highlighted lines).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since you are newer to Salesforce, I would recommend starting with a tool such as [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries/wiki/Getting-Started-With-DLRS)

What you're talking about is a related list. Those records have a field on them that is storing the Id of the contact record. Because of that, they are visible on this page.

Normally you would do what you are trying to do using a [roll-up field](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm); however, those fields only work with [master-detail relationships](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/relationships_among_objects.htm). The contract to contact relationship is probably  a lookup field so roll-up fields wont work. This is where that tool comes into play.

Answer (score -1):

the highlighted section is showing a related list. These are objects that are connected to the Contact via a lookup field. Anytime you add a lookup to a parent object, the child object will be available as a related list on the page layout. It is unclear what you want to add to the Contact object in your question. If the values that you want to use are on a related object, you can access them without adding new fields to the contact. To access via SOQL see this doc: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm